# error flagged in vs code, in routes/web.php file laravel 8, Undefined type 'App'. Anyone know how to get around this?

Tags: laravel

error flagged in vs code, in routes/web.php file laravel 8. Anyone know how to get around this?

```
if (App::environment('production')) {
    URL::forceScheme('https');
}
```

error >  Undefined type 'App'

Comment: add use App; on top of your route class.

Comment: I put it but the error still remains

Comment: Try this : app() - >environment('production')

Comment: yes , it worked perfectly, thanks (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead of App : app() - >environment('production')

Answer (score 0):

Add to your **AppServiceProvider** in the boot()

```
if($this->app->environment('production')) {
    URL::forceScheme('https');
}
```